# How to group by nested by key in array and calculate sum , avg in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of data  in the below format

```
let people=[
  {
    aggregationType: "1",
    coefficient: 0.03,
    id: "p1",
    name: "petter",
    type: "Number",
    age: 14
  },
  {
    aggregationType: "0",
    coefficient: 1,
    id: "p2",
    name: "mary",
    type: "Number",
    value: 24
  },
  {
    aggregationType: "1",
    coefficient: 0.03,
    id: "p1",
    name: "Amee",
    type: "Number",
    value: 32
  },
  {
    aggregationType: "0",
    coefficient: 1,
    id: "p2",
    name: "Mtp",
    type: "Number",
    value: 33
  },
  {
    aggregationType: "1",
    coefficient: 0.03,
    id: "p1",
    name: "Louis",
    type: "Number",
    value: 44
  },
]
```

I want to grouped the dataset by the 'id' and check the condition: if key aggregationType = 0 then calculate sum age, if key aggregationType = 1 then calculate Avg age.
And multiply by key 'coefficient' so that the desired result should be like this.

```
output=[
  [
    "p1", 0.9  // equivalent to ((14 + 32 + 44)/3)*0.03 aggregationType = 1 ==> calculate avg age,coefficient: 0.03
  ],
  [
    "p2", 57  // equivalent to (24+33)*1 = 57  aggregationType = 0 ==> calculate sum age, coefficient: 1
  ]
]
```

I tried to write this function but I don't know how to continue.

```
let result = {};

for ( let { id, aggregationType, value } of task ) 
{ 
  result[id] = result[id] || [];
  result[id].push({aggregationType, value }); 
}
console.log(result);
/*
// group by id
result = {
  p1: [
    {
      aggregationType: "1",
      value: 14
    },
    {
      aggregationType: "1",
      value: 32
    },
    {
      aggregationType: "1",
      value: 44
    }
  ],
  p2: [
    {
      aggregationType: "0",
      value: 24
    },
    {
      aggregationType: "0",
      value: 33
    },
    
  ]
}

*/
let newResult=[];
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(result)) {
    newResult = [key, value.reduce((a, e) => {
    if (e.aggregationType === '0') {
        a += e.value ;
    } else {
       (a += e.value) / value.length;
    }
     return a;
}, 0)]
}
```

Please help me, thank you!

Comment: Did you find an answer acceptable?

Comment: @trincot 
Your answer results as I desired.
I have not used the set, get in js ever so I will learn more

Comment: Using a Map (with get, set) is a way to avoid a time complexity of *O(n²)*. When input is very large, this can make a huge difference in performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, you could try to use `filter` function to filter your `people` based on `aggregation` and then use a `forEach` to calculate result:

```js
let people=[
          {
            aggregationType: "1",
            coefficient: 0.03,
            id: "p1",
            name: "petter",
            type: "Number",
            value: 14
          },
          {
            aggregationType: "0",
            coefficient: 1,
            id: "p2",
            name: "mary",
            type: "Number",
            value: 24
          },
          {
            aggregationType: "1",
            coefficient: 0.03,
            id: "p1",
            name: "Amee",
            type: "Number",
            value: 32
          },
          {
            aggregationType: "0",
            coefficient: 1,
            id: "p2",
            name: "Mtp",
            type: "Number",
            value: 33
          },
          {
            aggregationType: "1",
            coefficient: 0.03,
            id: "p1",
            name: "Louis",
            type: "Number",
            value: 44
          },
        ]
        let result = [];
        let aggregationType = ["0", "1"];  //put here all the aggregation types you need
        aggregationType.forEach(aggregation => {
           let peopleFiltered = people.filter(el => el.aggregationType === aggregation)
           let sum = 0;
           let id = "";
           peopleFiltered.forEach(el => {
              sum = sum + (el.value * el.coefficient);
              id = el.id;
           })
           let partialResult = [];
           if (aggregation === "0") {
              partialResult = [ id, sum ]
           }
           else if(aggregation === "1") {
              partialResult = [ id, sum/peopleFiltered.length ]
           }
// extend this 'if...else if' to add new calculation for different aggregation
           
           result.push(partialResult)
        })

        
        console.log(result)
```

Comment: id p1 and p2 not fixed, i can have p3 p4 .... please help me.. thank u

Comment: @oneeyes I updated my answer with a dynamic solution (you have only to add all the aggregation you want to `aggregationType ` array and extend if...esleif with all the aggregation calculations you need)

Comment: This solution has a time complexity of *O(n²)*, while it can be done with *O(n)* time complexity.

Comment: @Giovanni Esposito may i ask you more. In case the people array has both aggregationType =1 and = 0, the program is desired . if 
aggregationType can = 0 or 1 then
your program will not run as expected. 
For example : https://jsfiddle.net/681gktox/14/

Comment: @oneeyes you could remove `"0"` from `aggregationType` array like `let aggregationType = ["1"];`. This is the faster solution, but if you need something more dynamic let me know :)

Comment: @Giovanni Esposito 
I want in case `aggregationType` = 0 or =1, which is grouped by p1,p2 and calculations.
If remove "0" or "1" in `aggregationType` array , In case the array people has aggregationtype = 1 and 0, the result is not desired

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gioexp/w4nmtxy8/32/ I wrote some comments on code. Let me know if there is something unclear or wrong

Answer (score 1):

As you could have more than two distinct `id` values, I would suggest creating a Map keyed by `id` where in the corresponding values you store the corresponding aggregation type, coeefficient, and keep track of sum and count.

Then after the accumulation you can extract the values from this Map into the desired output format:

```js
function aggregate(people) {
    let map = new Map;
    for (let {aggregationType, coefficient, id, age} of people) {
        let entry = map.get(id);
        if (!entry) map.set(id, entry = { aggregationType, coefficient, sum: 0, count: 0 });
        entry.sum += age;
        entry.count++;
    }
    return Array.from(map, ([id, { aggregationType, coefficient, sum, count}]) => 
        [id, (+aggregationType ? sum / count : sum) * coefficient]
    );
}

let people=[{aggregationType: "1",coefficient: 0.03,id: "p1",name: "petter",type: "Number",age: 14},{aggregationType: "0",coefficient: 1,id: "p2",name: "mary",type: "Number",age: 24},{aggregationType: "1",coefficient: 0.03,id: "p1",name: "Amee",type: "Number",age: 32},{aggregationType: "0",coefficient: 1,id: "p2",name: "Mtp",type: "Number",age: 33},{aggregationType: "1",coefficient: 0.03,id: "p1",name: "Louis",type: "Number",age: 44},]

console.log(aggregate(people));
```

Comment: hello sir.
What do you mean by code `+aggregationType` .   ([id, (+aggregationType ? sum / count : sum) * coefficient])

Comment: The `+` is the unary plus: it converts its argument to number, so it will be 0 or 1. 0 is falsy, 1 is truthy for the ternary operator, so that means when `aggregationType` is "1", this will evaluate to `sum / count`, and when it is "0", just `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let people=[{aggregationType: "1",coefficient: 0.03,id: "p1",name: "petter",type: "Number",value: 14},{aggregationType: "0",coefficient: 1,id: "p2",name: "mary",type: "Number",value: 24},{aggregationType: "1",coefficient: 0.03,id: "p1",name: "Amee",type: "Number",value: 32},{aggregationType: "0",coefficient: 1,id: "p2",name: "Mtp",type: "Number",value: 33},{aggregationType: "1",coefficient: 0.03,id: "p1",name: "Louis",type: "Number",value: 44}];

var data = {};
people.forEach(function(item, index){
    data[item.id] = data[item.id] || {};
    data[item.id]['result'] = data[item.id]['result'] || 0;
    data[item.id]['values'] = data[item.id]['values'] || [];
    data[item.id]['values'].push(item.value)
    if('1' === item.aggregationType) {
        data[item.id]['result'] =  data[item.id]['values'].reduce(function(a,b){ return a + b},0) / data[item.id]['values'].length * item.coefficient;
    } else {
         data[item.id]['result'] = data[item.id]['result'] + item.value
    }

});

console.log(data.p1.result)
console.log(data.p2.result)
```